# Error propagation for inferential statistics?

Tags: inference, error-propagation

Assuming we have two samples from two populations each containing 10 independent observations + standard deviation. How should I propagate the error of the measurements themselves into the sampling error?

Example:

Blood samples were taken from 20 male individuals, 10 from individuals randomly sampled from a population of anemic patients, and 10 from an independent age-matched healthy male population. For each individual blood sample, I measured a protein, which according to the analytical method used, has a standard deviation associated with it, e.g., 10 ng/mL ± 0.2 ng/mL.

Now, for the whole data set, If I was to model the difference between the means in anemic vs. healthy patients, how would I propagate the errors?

```
df <- structure(list(value = c(10.9746643444716, 11.8215643507607, 
10.0904398058947, 7.72063101668958, 11.132160205841, 9.90175385296537, 
10.7130307588643, 9.14277089370172, 8.98963479613762, 10.7345886475362, 
5.02005913129535, 3.94591286780404, 5.88269731881474, 4.9076856062703, 
2.61720608462012, 2.84253207675305, 4.06644378220811, 4.60858489634185, 
3.23740211847406, 2.23776928808866), sd = c(0.133358425507811, 
0.114107348166208, 0.111754990370393, 0.135922789945039, 0.0323765045192955, 
0.0848776334673558, 0.0801350324665742, 0.063359998506837, 0.0811735414300104, 
0.150197358507943, 0.00992790714255545, 0.0434082629014837, 0.103808450495596, 
0.0341798509894078, 0.06395272211175, 0.0991172347676062, 0.122222651013611, 
0.172497320052591, 0.0383064081152008, 0.0615236705789717), group = c("healthy", 
"healthy", "healthy", "healthy", "healthy", "healthy", "healthy", 
"healthy", "healthy", "healthy", "anemic", "anemic", "anemic", 
"anemic", "anemic", "anemic", "anemic", "anemic", "anemic", "anemic"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

summary(lm(value ~ group, df))

Call:
lm(formula = value ~ group, data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.40149 -1.00804  0.06955  0.88217  1.94607 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    3.9366     0.3808   10.34 5.35e-09 ***
grouphealthy   6.1855     0.5385   11.48 1.02e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.204 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8799,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8733 
F-statistic: 131.9 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 1.018e-09
```

I wonder if a hierarchical model through linear mixed models can help. I've seen some people suggesting just weighting the individual values by the inverse of the variance of the error in the measurement.